Unresolved reference: serviceOf
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 991 ms

Configure project :gradle-plugin
e: file:///D:/office_Project/Project%2001/poolspacustomer-dev/poolspacustomer-dev/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/build.gradle.kts:54:11: Unresolved reference: serviceOf

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'D:_ProjectLocation_\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\build.gradle.kts' line: 54

What went wrong:
Script compilation error:
Line 54:           serviceOf()
^ Unresolved reference: serviceOf


1 error

Try:


Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


This question is similar to: react native 0.73.9 build fails with unresolved reference 'serviceOf' in @react-native/gradle-plugin/build.gradle.kts since upgrading to gradle 8.10. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
